# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE sqlalchemy and python to mysql db

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use `LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE` with sqlalchemy to upload batch files to my server. I have edited my `/etc/mysql/my.conf` to contain `local-infile == 1` under both `[mysql]` and `[mysqld]`, yet I'm getting this traceback when I run the program.

The relevant line of code is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 48, in <module>
    con.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/eoddata/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 906, in execute
    return self._execute_text(object, multiparams, params)
  File "/Users/eoddata/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1054, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "/Users/eoddata/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/Users/eoddata/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1332, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/Users/eoddata/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/Users/eoddata/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/Users/eoddata/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 442, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/Users/eoddata/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/Users/eoddata/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1148, 'The used command is not allowed with 
this MySQL version') [SQL: "LOAD DATA LOCAL
 INFILE 'stocks/AMEX_20150420.txt' INTO TABLE database.new_table\n                    
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (Symbol,@Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume)\n                    
SET Date = STR_TO_DATE(@Date,'%%Y%%m%%d');"]
```

I've done some research from the docs and can't find a way to fix this error. With python MySQLdb (from `pip install MySQL-Python`) will allow me to pass in a local-infile paramter. I can't find an equivalent in SQLAlchemy. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I've worked on this all night and still haven't made any progress - a lot of dead ends. Any ideas?

Thanks, Jared

Answer (score 12):

You should add `local_infile=1` to the connection string.

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql://user:pass@localhost/dbname?charset=utf8&local_infile=1"
```